# foreach with if

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, if

Доброго дня. Стоить задача выбрать из массив `id` по названию `$data = "Калуга"`
сам массив:

```
$getAccount = [groups] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48699
                [name] => Калуга
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48702
                [name] => Краснодар2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48705
                [name] => Ростов-на -Дону
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48708
                [name] => Архангельск
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48711
                [name] => Пермь
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48714
                [name] => Белгород
            )
    )
```

мой пример не работает :

```
$get = array();
foreach ($getAccount["groups"] as $key => $val) {
    if($get[$key]["name"] == $data){
        return $get[$key]["id"] = $val;
    }
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($get, true).'</pre>';
die();
```

буду признателен, если укажите на ошибку

Comment: или используйте array_filter()

Answer (score 1):

вы используете значение value как индекс, в то время как оно - подмассив, поэтоиу

```
foreach ($getAccount["groups"] as $k =>$value) {
    if((string)$getAccount["groups"][$k]["name"] == (string)$data){
        $id_group = $getAccount["groups"][$k]["id"];
        break;
    }
}
```

или так

```
foreach ($getAccount["groups"] as $value) {
    if((string) $value["name"] == (string)$data){
        $id_group = $value["id"];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое !! давно не писал на php ... правильно заминусовали вопрос

Comment: да не за что - тут все очень просто

Comment: а если несколько "калуг" то результатом будет первое вхождение, так и должно быть?

Comment: @Invision  ответить на вопрос должно ли быть так мне трудно, ориентировался на break в коде, а переделать на массив - легко :)

Answer (score 1):

Реализация на PHP >= 5.5 без использования `foreach`

```
$groupId = array_search($data, array_column($getAccount['groups'], 'name', 'id'));
```

Результат

```
48699
```

Comment: на локальном компе работает , на хостиге Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() видимо версия старая php на хостинге